# Why won't TeamCity connect to MySQL when using docker-compose?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, teamcity

I'm trying to get TeamCity server running using `docker-compose`. Here's my compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: teamcity-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=teamcity
    volumes: 
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'

  teamcity:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server
    container_name: teamcity
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: 
      - datadir:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
      - logs:/opt/teamcity/logs
    ports:
      - "8111:8111"

volumes:
  mysql:
  datadir:
  logs:
```

I've been successful getting wordpress set up using a very similar technique, and I can run phpMyAdmin and link it to the MySQL container and see the database, so its there.

When I browse to the teamcity web address, it shows me the initial setup screen as expected. I tell it to use MySQL and I put in 'root' as teh username and my MySQL root password. Teamcity then shows this:

[image]

I'm sure it's something simple but I just can't see what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! Here is my solution and some other learnings.

The problem was that I was telling TeamCity to use 'localhost' as the database server URL. This seems intuitive because all the services are on the same machine, but is incorrect. It is as if each container is its own host and so 'localhost' is specific to each container. 'localhost' inside a container refers to the container itself, not the host machine or any other container. So 'localhost' on the teamcity service refers to the teamcity server, not the database server, and that's why it couldn't connect.

The correct address for the database server based on my `docker-compose.yml` file is `db` (the service name of the database container). The service name becomes the host name for that container and docker resolves these as DNS names correctly within the composed group.

Also note: the `default` virtual network is created implicitly by `docker-compose` and allows all of the containers in the composed group to communicate with each other. The name of this network derives from the folder where the `docker-compose.yml` file is located (in my case `~/projects/teamcity`) so I get a network called `teamcity_default`. All servers on this private vitual network are visible to each other with no further configuration needed.

The `teamcity` server container explicitly exposes port `8111` on the host's network interface, so it is the only container visible to the outside world. You do not need to (and probably should not) expose ports if you only need the servers to talk to each other. For example, the database server does not need to have a `ports` entry because it is automatically exposed on the private inter-container network. This is great for security because all the back-end services are hidden from the physical LAN and therefore the Internet.